# Return SQL query in specific chunks?

Tags: mysql

I have a time stamped data for specific dates in my mysql database. Whenever I retrieve the data in different ways, this is what I usually get:

[image]

I'm trying to get this query to look like this

[image]

What I want is to return different/distinct rows for date1 while keeping time ordered. If you look at the desired result, you will see that date1 starts with Sep then Oct then goes back to Sep, Oct etc. I hope this makes it clear.

**Note: This is just an example, the real data have four different dates in date1 column so I'm expecting every four rows to have a different entry of date1**

Comment: I don't understand what the difference you want is. What does your current query look like?

Comment: You want to alternate dates instead of grouping all the rows with the same date together?

Comment: The order is different in the second picture

Comment: Yes I want to alternate dates

Comment: Grouping by won't help since I don't want to do anything with the grouped data except return it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to specify an `order by` clause.

```
select
  ...
from
  ...
where
  ...
order by
  date2
  , time
```

Comment: This won't alternate the dates

Comment: What do you mean "alternate the dates"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: This is wrong. Look at the desired result, it has `time = 6:04` before `time = 6:02`

Comment: @Barmar: hm... you're right. I guess I'm at a loss as to what exactly the OP wants.

Comment: he wants to alternate between 1-sep and 2-sep in the output

Comment: He also said that in the real data there are 4 dates, so it should rotate through them.

Comment: What I want is to return different/distinct rows for date1 while keeping time ordered. If you look at the desired result, you will see that date1 starts with Sep then Oct then goes back to Sep, Oct etc. I hope this makes it clear.